# Insights into React Render LifeCycle

Tags: reactjs, antd

> How can I ensure that `isFormValid` function is executed, every time
>   First Name, Last Name (& some more fields on the form) changes?

```
const BusinessInformation = React.memo(({ form, ...props }) => {
  const isFormValid = () => {
    debugger;
    const fieldsError = form.getFieldsError();
    const areAllErrorsUndefined = Object.values(fieldsError).every(el => el === undefined);
    return areAllErrorsUndefined;
  }
  const handleClickOnSetup = (props) => {
    debugger;
  }
  const [invalidFormState] = useState(false)
  const { getFieldDecorator } = form;
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Form.Item className="firstName">
        {getFieldDecorator("firstName", {
          rules: [
            { required: true, message: 'What is your first name?' }
          ]
        })(<Input placeholder="First Name" />)}
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item className="lastName">
        {getFieldDecorator("lastName", {
          rules: [
            { required: true, message: 'What is your lastName name?' }
          ]
        })(<Input placeholder="Last Name" />)}
      </Form.Item>
      {
        console.log('form.getFieldsError()' + form.getFieldsError())
      }
      {**!isFormValid()** && (<span> Please fill all required fields</span>)}
      <Form.Item>
        <Button htmlType="submit" onClick={handleClickOnSetup}>Submit</Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </div>)
});

export default BusinessInformation;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `useEffect` to do that something like this:

```
 useEffect(()=>{
    console.log('changed');
    isFormValid();
    },[form.getFieldValue('firstName'),form.getFieldValue('lastName')])
```

generally useEffect gets called whenever any of the values you give in the array changes
so it gets called whenever the `firstname` or `lastname` changes but remember it gets called for the firsttime it renders.... you can avoid that as well.. for more info see [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Comment: Thanks, +1 for the pointers, @arvind, my form has 50s of fields, would you recommend something else in this case pls?

Comment: @Abhijeet  in each form item inside the decorators you can have validators(function) and make your validations over there.. you can also call the function on form submission... there you can validate all the fields...